# Sitecore - Manipulating URL's

Tags: sitecore

Sitecore generates URL's based on the item names defined in the Sitecore tree,

```
http://samplewebsite/Pages/Sample Page
```

But our client is interested to lower the case of all URL's (pages/sample page), and format the blank spaces with hyphen (sample-page).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your web.config, you can add  `<replace find=" " mode="on" replacewith="-">` in the `<encodeNameReplacements>` node to format spaces with hyphens. Be careful though - that will mean you aren't able to use hyphens in item names anymore (as Sitecore will try and find an item with a space in it)

To lower-case your URLs you could use the rule engine, like John West describes here:
[Use the Sitecore Rules Engine to Control Item Names](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Use-the-Sitecore-Rules-Engine-to-Control-Item-Names.aspx)

Comment: It's worth noting that a few more options are added to the LinkManager configuration in the web.config for Sitecore 6.6 `<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="true" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />`. Lowercase URLs is one of the new options.

Comment: One more thing I would think about is that when clients ask for these things, they usually also mean that they want request URLs with uppercase letters or spaces to be rejected. By default Sitecore will still accept them. For this reason, I normally add a processor to the start of the HttpRequestBegin pipeline that redirects non-compliant URL's to their correct equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a custom config file in App_Config/Include you can use the following config patches between your `<sitecore>` and `</sitecore>` tags. This will change spaces to dashes in your URL and not allow content editors to use dashes in their item names.

```
<encodeNameReplacements>
  <!-- Replace spaces in URLs with dashes -->
  <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />
</encodeNameReplacements>
<settings>
  <setting name="InvalidItemNameChars">
    <!-- Disallow dashes in item names for content editors because the above rule causes the page to crash -->
    <patch:attribute name="value">-\/:?&quot;&lt;&gt;|[]</patch:attribute>
  </setting>
</settings>
```

Comment: Possibly worth noting that there is a bug in SC 7.2 which means including an &quot; in the patch file means it does not get applied correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Space to hyphen replacement can be done with `<encodeNameReplacements>` part of `Sitecore.config`.

To use lowercase characters for all of urls, you need to extend `LinkManager` class. Both of them are explained here:

http://csuwannarat.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/how-i-make-seo-friendly-sitecore-urls/

Answer (score 0):

John West also has an excellent solution posted here: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Use-the-Sitecore-Rules-Engine-to-Control-Item-Names.aspx